# How to make a program that verifies Card Security Codes in python?

Tags: python, validation, python-2.7, if-statement

I want to make a program that verifies Card Security Codes (CSC, 3 digit security code on credit cards) in python. I want to write a simple program that checks if a given code is valid. The code is valid if all the three characters entered are digits between 0 and 9. If the CSC is valid, I want the program to display a massage saying that it is valid and a different message saying that it is not valid if the entered code does not consist of three digits.

I wrote the following code but I know it is wrong. How can I make it write but keep it short and simple?

```
code = raw_input("Please enter CSC: ")

if code[0] in range [0,10] and code[1] in range [0,10] and code[2] in range [0,10]:
    print "Thank you. We will process your order!"
else:
    print "The verification code was not valid. Please check your credit card code again."
```

Would very much appreciate your help!

Comment: `'[0, 10]' != '(0, 10)'`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can check to see if the length is correct:

```
if len(code) == 3:
```

And check to see if it is a number:

```
if code.isdigit():
```

**Edit:** proper syntax:

```
if len(code) == 3 and code.isdigit():
```

Comment: I don't know how to do it this way. If I do the following i get an error:

code = raw_input("Please enter CSC: ")

    if len(code) == 3:
   
    if code.isnumeric():
   
     print "Thank you. We will process your order!"
    else:
        
print "The verification code was not valid. Please check your credit card code again."

Comment: I'll edit with proper syntax. I wanted to show both separately.

Comment: No, I get an error in isnumeric. Do I have to import anything before I can use isnumeric?

Comment: @user2357 You need to use `.isdigit()` not `.isnumeric`

Comment: It's because I am a gringo and got my languages mixed up.  `.isdigit()` is correct in Python 2.7

Answer (score 2):

Use a regular expression, and match `\d{3}`:

```
import re
m = re.match('\d{3}', code)
if m:
    print 'Yay!'
else:
    print 'Fail!'
```

Answer (score 2):

Or:

```
import re
if re.match("[0-9][0-9][0-9]", code) == None:
    print "Not valid"
else:
    Print "Valid"
```

Answer (score 1):

There are better ways, but your code is ALMOST right. Change each instance of `range [0,10]` to `map(str, range(0,10))` and it will work. Be aware though that if I give the input as `"123cucumbers"` it will approve my input :)

This may be a good application for regular expressions, but honestly I think that's a bit overkill for this. Try this instead:

```
def validCSC(csc):
    if not len(csc) == 3:
        return False
    try:
        csc = int(csc) # turn it into a number
    except ValueError: # input isn't a number
        return False
    if 100 <= csc <= 999:
        return True
    else:
        return False
```

Answer (score 1):

I decided to do it like this:

```
code = raw_input("Please enter CSC: ")

if len(code) == 3 and code[0] in map(str, range(0,10)) and code[1] in map(str, range(0,10)) and code[2] in map(str, range(0,10)):
    print "Thank you. We will process your order!"
else:
    print "The verification code was not valid. Please check your credit card code again."
```

It works but would it work for all cases?

Thank you very much for the answers!

Comment: It will approve `012`, which I'm not sure is correct behavior. Louis's answer is better, IMO. Mapping `range(10)` to `str` three times is also ugly and costly, I was just trying to make limited edits to your code.

Comment: You are right, I will do it Louis's way. I am still new to python, been learning it for about 2 weeks so I still don't see the ugliness :D